# Include Arabic characters in JavaScript regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, arabic

So im using jquery validation on my script to only allows certain characters. I've had a request to allow the script to use arabic characters aswell. How would i do this?

Heres my current code:

```
    $.validator.addMethod(
    "legalname",
    function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9()._\-\s]+$/.test(value);
    },
    "Illegal character. Only points, spaces, underscores or dashes are allowed."
);
```

Comment: Search for "javascript unicode regex" - the middle word is important. (Unfortunately there are no explicit unicode character classes ..)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Via [this site](http://kourge.net/projects/regexp-unicode-block) you can easily create unicode regex for many languages:

Arabic:

```
[\u0600-\u06FF]
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
function HasArabicCharacters(text)
{
    var arregex = /[\u0600-\u06FF]/;
    alert(arregex.test(text));
}
```

For more info take a look here [Arabic Unicode block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_Unicode_block)