# How do I extract hashtags from non-English strings?

Tags: ruby, regex

I am using this code to extract hashtags from posts in my Rails 3.2.13 application. I am also using Ruby 1.9.3.

```
hasy =/(?:\s|^)(?:#(?!(?:\d+|\w+?_|_\w+?)(?:\s|$)))(\w+)(?=\s|$)/i
tags =post.body.scan(hasy).join(',').split(',').map{|i| "#"+i}
```

The code is working great for English words but for other languages, specially Arabic, they are not working.
Does anyone have ideas to solve the problem, as my site uses a lot of Arabic text.

Comment: You should give a sample string and expected output also...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847333/include-arabic-characters-in-javascript-regular-expression

Comment: how about replacing `\w+` with `\S+` (or perhaps something similar, negate white-space and punctuation for example).

Comment: @smerny its not working

Comment: Try `(\w+|[\u0600-\u06FF]+)`

Comment: We can't help you without sample input and expected output, and, without those, this is an improper question, so help us help you by adding the needed information _to your question_, not in comments. See http://sscce.org/

Comment: for example "#القاهرة " gives me nil but "#cairo" gives me #cairo

Comment: @hwnd after adding (\w+|[\u0600-\u06FF]+) its working now ,I tested it here http://rubular.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend looking at the Regexp documentation for the POSIX character classes. There are several that might fit your needs. I'd recommend `[:graph:]` as a starting point, then narrow it down if needed.

From [the docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html):

```
/[[:alnum:]]/ - Alphabetic and numeric character
/[[:alpha:]]/ - Alphabetic character
/[[:blank:]]/ - Space or tab
/[[:cntrl:]]/ - Control character
/[[:digit:]]/ - Digit
/[[:graph:]]/ - Non-blank character (excludes spaces, control characters, and similar)
/[[:lower:]]/ - Lowercase alphabetical character
/[[:print:]]/ - Like [:graph:], but includes the space character
/[[:punct:]]/ - Punctuation character
/[[:space:]]/ - Whitespace character ([:blank:], newline, carriage return, etc.)
/[[:upper:]]/ - Uppercase alphabetical
/[[:xdigit:]]/ - Digit allowed in a hexadecimal number (i.e., 0-9a-fA-F)
```

> Ruby also supports the following non-POSIX character classes:

```
/[[:word:]]/ - A character in one of the following Unicode general categories Letter, Mark, Number, Connector_Punctuation
```

For your purposes, something like:

```
/\s(#[[:graph:]]+)/
```

[will capture your two sample strings](http://rubular.com/r/cixM2N9XSy). The previous Rubular link has examples.

Answer (score 2):

`\w` will only match ASCII characters. You can use [POSIX bracket expressions](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Regexp.html#label-Character+Classes) in your regex to also match non-ASCII characters that are considered to be an alphabetic character in Unicode.

```
str = "some text before #القاهرة more text here القاهرة #foobar"
str.scan(/#[[:alnum:]]+/)
# => ["#القاهرة", "#foobar"]
```

Comment: it won't work because Arabic is written from the right to left. str.scan(/[[:alnum:]]#+/) will probably be better.

Comment: More likely, the bytes start with `#` but the BiDi is set up to render them right to left.

Answer (score 0):

`[^\x20-\x7E]+` will recognise the non-ASCII chars.