# Regular expression jQuery validator include non English characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Well, I have a validator for a website URL. It works perfectly, but I need add the ability to type non-English characterss like Arabic, etc. I know a little about regular expressions, but I don't know how I can allow Arabic characters here, for example, instead \w or \a.

```
$('#WebSiteTextbox').blur(function () {

    patternurl = /([\d\w]+?:\/\/)?([\w\d\.\-]+)(\.\w+)(:\d{1,5})?(\/\S*)?/i
    if (!patternurl.test($("#WebSiteTextbox").val())) {
        $(this).attr('value','');
        $('.ValidatorError').html('Not Valid').slideDown().delay(5000).promise().done(function () {
            $(this).slideUp();
        });
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sobkqfa6/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include Arabic characters in JavaScript regular expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847333/include-arabic-characters-in-javascript-regular-expression)

Comment: no I saw that before, it's not in my case @Emissary

Comment: @jiff "*chars like Arabic and etc*" - What do you mean by `etc` specifically?

Comment: @jiff it is your case... you can't use `\w` - the shorthands only encompass a small alphabet - you have to specify the unicode range instead.

Comment: yes you right but that answer didn't help me out. I used that but didn't work in my case. please see: http://jsfiddle.net/sobkqfa6/1/ @Emissary

Comment: @Mariano it was an example, you just consider arabic and persian

Comment: @jiff please include in your question why the linked answer did not help you out. This way people won't close this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the specific character ranges for Arabic and Persian characters. `\w` can be expressed as `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. You can include any character range in that same [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

From [Arabic script in Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode):

> 1. Arabic (0600—06FF, 255 characters)
>
>    1. Arabic-Indic Digits (0660-0669)
>    2. Extended Arabic-Indic Digits (06F0-06F9)
> 2. Arabic Supplement (0750—077F, 48 characters)
> 3. Arabic Extended-A (08A0—08FF, 50 characters)
> 4. Arabic Presentation Forms-A (FB50—FDFF, 611 characters)
> 5. Arabic Presentation Forms-B (FE70—FEFF, 140 characters)
> 6. Rumi Numeral Symbols (10E60—10E7F, 31 characters)
> 7. Arabic Mathematical Alphabetic Symbols (1EE00—1EEFF, 143 characters)
>
> ---
>
> The basic Arabic range encodes the standard letters and diacritics,
>   but does not encode contextual forms (U+0621–U+0652 being directly
>   based on ISO 8859-6); and also includes the most common diacritics and
>   Arabic-Indic digits. The Arabic Supplement range encodes letter
>   variants mostly used for writing African (non-Arabic) languages. The
>   Arabic Extended-A range encodes additional Qur'anic annotations and
>   letter variants used for various non-Arabic languages. The Arabic
>   Presentation Forms-A range encodes contextual forms and ligatures of
>   letter variants needed for Persian, Urdu, Sindhi and Central Asian
>   languages. The Arabic Presentation Forms-B range encodes spacing forms
>   of Arabic diacritics, and more contextual letter forms. The
>   presentation forms are present only for compatibility with older
>   standards, and are not currently needed for coding text. The Arabic
>   Mathematical Alphabetical Symbols block encodes characters used in
>   Arabic mathematical expressions.

I think you should include:

- In `\w`: **1** and **3**
- In `\d`: **1.1**

I believe this would include English, Arabic and Persian:

```
/(\w+:\/\/)?([-.a-z0-9_\u0600-\u06FF\u08A0-\u08FF]+)(\.\w+)(:\d{1,5})?(\/\S*)?/i
```

- I am assuming you can't have Arabic characters in the protocol, the extension and the port number, only in the domain.

Comment: @jiff I'm glad it did. I should have mentioned though I don't speak Arabic so I'd recommend checking for *special* characters such as accents or diacritics to verify they're included in that range.

Comment: yeah, sure, have to check. Thanks a lot.