# How to convert PHP regex to match Arabic characters to JS regex

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I have this **English** and **Arabic** `regex` in php , it works fine with php

But its not working with this library [Formvalidation.io](http://formvalidation.io/validators/regexp/)

```
~^[a-z0-9٠-٩\-+,()/'\s\p{Arabic}]{1,}$~iu
```

> I need to make it work and convert into JS regex to use in formvalidation regex.

[Demo Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/uS4rC4/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Arabic regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12847517/3832970) is:

```
[\u0600-\u06FF]
```

Actually, `٠-٩` is a subset of this Arabic range, so I think you can remove them from the pattern.

So, in JS it will be

```
/^[a-z0-9+,()\/'\s\u0600-\u06FF-]+$/i
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vT1aO7/2)

Comment: Yes Thanks it worked. i will accept when it allow me. Upvoted.