# RegExp expression to Accept Alphanumeric values with all Special Charac

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a Reg Expression to check if the Language is English or Arabic.

My field under test is used to capture SMS messages. The message can be in

```
English with numbers & special characters

OR

Arabic with English numbers/Arabic numbers & special characters
```

Search should be on multiline accepting space & enter.
Check is to allocate the numbers of characters permissible per language. Eg: English allows 160; while Arabic allows only 70 per SMS

I assume the Exp should only check the words (first few to decide the language)

here is a sample of what I wrote in JavaScript; Regex did not work, only RegExp :

```
var pat = new RegExp("^[A-Za-z0-9\s!@#$%^&*()_+=-`~\\\]\[{}|';:/.,?><]*$");
```

But for the below string it fails :

```
"Hello & Hi"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: When using constructor, double-escape backslashes. `\s` ==> `\\s`. In character class, `-` has special meaning. To match `-` literally, you need to escape it.

Comment: Check [Javascript regex to allow specific characters in arabic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35577540/javascript-regex-to-allow-specific-characters-in-arabic/35581928#35581928) and [How to convert PHP regex to match Arabic characters to JS regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35036946/how-to-convert-php-regex-to-js-regex/35037002#35037002). Besides, put the `-` at the start/end of the character class, or escape it as Tushar suggested.

Comment: Or better yet, don't use `new RegExp` when you can use the literal form instead, `/regexhere/`.

Comment: Thank you Tushar for the correction, Crowder & Wiktor for your advice

Comment: So, you only need to match strings consisting of printable ASCII chars only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var regex=/^[ -~]+$/;
var str='Hello & Hi';
console.info(regex.test(str));
```

you can write like this too

Comment: Even better!! Thanks both answers are correct

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating the regular expression from string you need to escape `\` character to use `\s`. Also, you should either escape `-` or put it just before closing `]` when you are not using it to define a range of characters.

```js
var re = new RegExp("^[A-Za-z0-9\\s!@#$%^&*()_+=\-`~\\\]\[{}|';:/.,?><]*$");
console.log(re.test("Hello & Hi"));
```

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly!!; just that I added the hyphen at the very end.