# How to mask non Western Latin characters in BootsFaces and PrimeFaces?

Tags: primefaces, bootsfaces

I'm in need to add input mask for some input fields using PrimeFaces `p:inputMask` and BootsFaces `p:inputText`.
The required mask should only accept Arabic letters plus some numbers.
my problem is: I do not know how to do that, any help will be appreciate.

Comment: Thanks Jasper de Vries
But I think that input mask used to governs what a user is allowed to enter in as input in a text box. It can be said to be a template, or set format that entered data must conform to, mainly used for the purposes of data integrity by preventing transcription errors.

Comment: I 'un-bolded' your question

Comment: Please add a feature request at our [bug tracker](https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues). If @JasperdeVries is right, I can't promise we can solve the issue, but the minimum we can do is to forward your request to the JavaScript library we've used to implement the input masks.

Comment: @StephanRauh The only possibility I see (BootsFaces) is regexp which might already work. https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask#via-inputmask-class https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/blob/master/src/main/java/net/bootsfaces/component/inputText/InputTextRenderer.java#L319 `{ regex: "insertRegExpHere" }`. I'll check if it works. If not, then I can probably add / fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arabic characters can be matched using a regular expression. See [Include Arabic characters in JavaScript regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847333/include-arabic-characters-in-javascript-regular-expression)

### BootsFaces

#### 1.3 and up

BootsFaces 1.3 and up supports a regular expression in the mask like:

```
<b:inputText mask="{ regex: '[0-9\u0600-\u06FF]*' }" />
```

#### Before 1.3

BootsFaces ships with [Inputmask by Robin Herbots](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask). Before 1.3 the `mask` attribute in `b:inputText` only allows you to pass a mask expression. In a mask expression you cannot use regular expressions. However, [the Inputmask library does support regular expressions](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask#via-inputmask-class). You could create a workaround by omitting the `mask` attribute in `b:inputText`, and initialise the mask using JavaScript:

```
Inputmask({ regex: "[0-9\u0600-\u06FF]*" }).mask("input[type=text]");
```

`0-9` is for matching the numbers, `\u0600-\u06FF` is for matching the Arabic characters.
With `.mask("...")` you can select the inputs where the mask should apply.

### PrimeFaces

Up to this point (6.2) PrimeFaces `inputMask` does not support a regular expression. You could use `p:inputText` with [`p:keyFilter`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/keyFilter.xhtml) though:

```
<p:inputText>
  <p:keyFilter regEx="/[0-9\u0600-\u06FF]/"/>
</p:inputText>
```

Please note that PrimeFaces is using the JavaScript notation: `/pattern/`.

### Other languages

Your question is how to match Arabic characters in masks. Of course the same solution can be applied for other languages using non Western Latin characters, like:

- Chinese
- Hebrew
- Hindi
- Japanse
- Korean (Hangul)
- Russian (Cyrillic)

For each language / character set it is a matter of finding the right regular expression.

Comment: Just a little confirmation from the BootsFaces team: the addition Jasper describes has officially been integrated into the next version of BootsFaces. Thanks, Jasper, for contributing the code!

Comment: @Hasan, please read "[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)"

Comment: But when tried to applied your solution in bootsfaces it is not working and I failed to figure out what is wrong.
I added the suggested solution to my page as follows:

Comment: <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"
 template="/temp.xhtml">
              <ui:define name="content">
                <script type="text/javascript">
  var selector = document.getElementById("mInput");
  Inputmask({ regex: "[0-9\u0600-\u06FF]*" }).mask(selector);
  </script>
      <h:form>
         <b:inputText id="mInput"
   value="#{testBean.inputVal}" />
            </h:form>
              </ui:define >
     </ui:composition>

Comment: by the way I can not find the bootsfaces release you mentioned above. I only find BootsFaces 1.2.0 not BootsFaces 1.2.1

Comment: The ID in your script is wrong. It is prefixed withe the form's ID. 1.2.1 is not out yet. Use the DOM inspector to find the rendered HTML ID. I just provided the fix this week: https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/920

Comment: @Hasan BootsFaces 1.3.0 (containing this feature) is released!