# Angular 6 validators pattern for latin characters is not working

Tags: angular, validation, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I am using reactive forms with validators. For the arabic name field I am using:

```
Validators.pattern('[\u0600-\u06FF ]*')
```

But I can't figure out the pattern for latin letters of A-Z and a-z.

I tried:

```
Validators.pattern(/^-?([a-z]\d*)?$/)
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: [regexr](https://regexr.com/) is awesome for working out regular expressions

Answer (score 2):

try to apply this pattern: /^[ءآأؤإئابةتثجحخدذرزسشصضطظعغفقكلمنهوىيًٌٍَُِّْٰ]*$/

Comment: for arabic :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847333/include-arabic-characters-in-javascript-regular-expression

Answer (score 2):

i use this regex:

```
    Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_@\.]{2,20}$')
```

And

```
   Validators.pattern(/[\u0600-\u06FF-/ ]/) for arabic
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer was by simply using:

```
Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*')
```

To allow numbers with them:

```
Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*')
```