# Search in bulk or word (not letters)

Tags: javascript, search

I want to search inside the variable, but I don't want it to search for letters as an

example :

```
const myText = "Hi Here We go";
console.log(myText.includes("Here")) // true
console.log(myText.includes("ere")) // false
console.log(myText.includes("Here We")) // true
console.log(myText.includes("go")) // true
console.log(myText.includes("i")) // false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to turn the string to search for into a regular expression, and add word boundaries to the left and right side.

```js
const myText = "Hi Here We go";
console.log(/\bHere\b/.test(myText));
console.log(/\bere\b/.test(myText));
```

If you have to do it dynamically...

```js
const myText = "Hi Here We go";
const validate = needle => (new RegExp('\\b' + needle + '\\b')).test(myText);
console.log(validate('Here'));
console.log(validate('ere'));
```

Comment: It really worked!! But /\bHere\b/ what are you doing

Comment: As the answer says, I added word boundaries to the left and right side in a regular expression.

Comment: Not working with Arabic letters?

Comment: Arabic letters aren't word characters, so a boundary between an Arabic letter and a non-Arabic-letter won't be reliably matched by `\b`. For that you'll either need an approach like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29729391/9515207) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847333/include-arabic-characters-in-javascript-regular-expression/12847474) combined with lookarounds, or use a different approach. like positive lookarounds for spaces, string delimiters, commas, periods, etc.